# The use of "all" keyword in R function

Tags: r

I am trying to understand this older R code. A simplified piece like this:

```
> foo <- function(file_name) {
       df = read.csv(file_name, sep=",", header=T, skip=2)\
       df1 = df[,c("col1", "col2")]
       colnames(df1) = c("Col1", "Col2")
       list(df1, rest=df<-all)
  }
```

The df1 dataframe is returned as expected. But what's the purpose of having "df<-all"? Applying this operator to a data frame, I have this:

```
rest = df<-all
rest
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("all")
```

I think the original code's purpose was to extract all other columns than "col1" and "col2" from the original data frame.

Comment: As I am sure you looked up, `all` is a function that tests to see whether all sets of logical vectors are `TRUE`. You're guess about the intent is what I would guess too, but I think I would have written `rest = df[,-c("col1","col2")]` - I think that would work.

Comment: while the use of `<-` within a function call (assigning to a variable that can be reference later, while using this *value* in an argument to the overarching function call) is useful at times, I find its use in a return value to be questionable at best in concept. In this case, it makes absolutely no sense (to me) and is most likely a typo, bad programming, or something else (that is still wrong). Either way, this `foo` function should be re-evaluated in its intention, and likely reimplemented.

Comment: yeah, I rewind everything in the code. Looks like the "all" keyword should not be used in that way.